# trying to understand unlabled nasm pseudo-instructions

Tags: assembly, nasm

Im new to namn and assembly and was going through the manual, when i got stuck on the following.

Trying understand why one would declare pseudo-instructions without using labels.

Is it to align data, or why would one do this?

```
section .data
    db    0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04
    dw    0x1234
```

Comment: "Declare pseudo-instructions"? All that's being done is to place 6 bytes of data in the `.data` section.

Comment: well the nasm doc calls them pseudo-instructions (DB, DW, DD, DQ, DT, DO, DY and DZ) and yes i am aware that we place 6 bytes in the data secion. but my question is why would one do that. or was my question unclear ?

Comment: Perhaps some part of the code is referring to them relative to the start of the `.data` section. Or, in some cases (not saying that's the case here) you might want to have specific data at some location as some sort of header, where you really don't care about being able to reference that data from your code.

Comment: I think it's just an example in the manual to illustrate the syntax. In a real code, you would put a label, but that's another unrelated syntax.

Comment: Example if we want to use a sine table inside of the data segment, then we can address each content relative to the start address of the table, so we do not need for to label every value, only the beginning of the table.

Comment: @DirkWolfgangGlomp, ok that explains it. So basically you would need it for reserving space, and or padding data. Then i can assume that it will be sequential?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, to make something similar to C structs.
Consider this *Disk Address Packet* structure used with `INT13/AH=42h`.

```
Offset  Size    Description     (Table 00272)
00h    BYTE    size of packet (10h or 18h)
01h    BYTE    reserved (0)
02h    WORD    number of blocks to transfer (max 007Fh for Phoenix EDD)
04h    DWORD   -> transfer buffer
08h    QWORD   starting absolute block number
```

A function to set the transfer buffer could be:

```
push bp
mov bp, sp

mov bx, WORD [bp+04]    ;Address of struct base

mov ax, WORD [bp+06h]   ;Tx offset
mov WORD [bx+04h], ax

mov ax, WORD [bp+08h]   ;Tx segment
mov WORD [bx+06h], ax

pop bp
ret 06h
```

This function use relative addressing for setting the fields of the structs, this way it works with every struct regardless of the way it has been allocated.
In you program this structs are allocated dynamically so you don't need to define them in the data section, but one is statically allocated for some reason.
That could be defined as

```
DefaultDAP:
   db 18h
   db 00h
   dw 1
   dd 0
   dd 0
```

There is no need to name each field as the above function don't use label (but relative addressing), what counts is that `18h 00h 01h 00h 00h 00h 00h 00h 00h 00h 00h 00h` is emitted at the location of `DefaultDAP`.

Emitting data is useful in general, even for generating code. You could always use relative addressing to access data so actually a lot of labels could be avoided but that would make the code awful and less efficient (as the assembler can compute offset for you).

Answer (score 0):

From the [NASM Manual](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html):

DB, DW, DD, DQ, DT, DO, DY and DZ are used, much as in MASM, to declare initialized data.

```
db - define a byte
dw - define a word
```

Since the layout of an NASM source line is

```
label:    instruction operands        ; comment
```

this is why unlabelled instructions are called pseudo instructions.

**Pseudo Instructions** are some special instructions created by the assembler designer to facilitate mainly memory initialization and space reservation. These contain commands to the assembler itself.

```
section .data
    db    0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04    ; Initialize 4 bytes to 1h, 2h, 3h, 4h
    dw    0x1234                 ; Initialize 1 word (2 bytes) to 1234h
```

Comment: It's not true that "unlabelled instructions are called pseudo instructions."  On a line by itself, `add eax, ecx` isn't a pseudo-instruction.  `add` is a mnemonic for a real machine instruction.  But `dd` isn't.  Syntactically it works like an instruction, and emitting bytes into the output at the current position in the current section, but you won't find it in Intel's manuals.  That's why it's a pseudo-instruction.  (Some other ISAs make more use of pseudo-instructions in their asm source, like MIPS with `li $t0, 0x123456` assembling to `lui $t0, 0x56` (high half) / `addiu $t0, $t0, 0x1234`.

Comment: Also, `foo: db 1,2,3,4` doesn't make it a non-pseudo instruction.  Other than that middle section, your answer seems fine, especially the commented code block at the end.